# opengl-es draw lots of transformed objects efficiently

Tags: opengl-es, vbo, vertex-shader

I am writing an opengl es program to construct a large scene contains a lot of objects transformed from several based objects.
For example, the object A has about 700 vertices and 600 faces, and the geometry of objects a1, a2, a3, ..., a100 are transformed from object A with individual matrix(4*4).

So, I'd like to know if there is an efficiently way to draw these objects with optimal draw calls and bandwidth.
For example, is there a way to pass the transform matrixes into shader and generate the points for all those objects?

Comment: Yes, transformation matrices are typically passed into the vertex shader, and applied there. To get meaningful answers, you'll probably have to be more specific on where exactly you have a problem.

Comment: I should make it more clear. I have to call drawXXXXX for 100 times for each object. It's not efficient if there are lots of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Opengles3.0, I find drawXXXInstanced can handle it perfectly.